# Is it possible to access SQL Trace Data (same as what SQL Profiler can see) through python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server

Overview: I need to monitor traffic to the SQL server, and be able to extract some of the parameters, and determine which user sent the request. This all needs to be done in python.

I'm going to lay out how I need this to work, because I may be looking at it wrong.

I have User A, User B, and User C.  All three of these users are using an inventory software (very large program, made by a big company) to communicate with the Server. The server is running SQL Server 17.  I have a python application each user has installed on their computer and they are using alongside their inventory management software. This program gives the users the ability to do things the inventory software just simply doesn't offer. My python program uses PYODBC to connect to the SQL server and run queries to the same SQL database the inventory management server is already connected to.

I need my python software to be able to monitor the SQL queries sent between the inventory software on each users computer and the SQL server.  I can already do this by logging into the SQL server VM and opening up SQL Server Profiler and starting a trace.  But now I need to access that information inside my python application on each of the users computers.

The end goal here is for the python application on user A computer to be monitoring the SQL queries, and then a specific query is ran to the server (IE: exec StoredProc1 4, 500, 100) I need to be able to extract the parameters, and call functions to be able to display additional data in my python application.

The python program installed on User A's computer only needs to monitor traffic between user A and the server. I do not care about any traffic between any other computer and the server.

I tried to create an Extended Event Session, and log the data to a file, and just access that file with my python program to read from it, but the problem is this needs to happen in real time, and I could not access the .xel file while the SQL server is writing to it.

One "idea" I had was to instead of logging the data to a .xel file, I could instead insert it into a table, and then just select from the table with my python application every 1-2 seconds, but I am not sure how to set the Extended Event session to log the data into a table.  Another "idea" I had was to just monitor the packets sent from the users computer to the specific server IP address and port and try and dissect that, but I am not exactly sure this will work either.

If anyone has ever done anything like this and has any input on how to best make this work, without taxing the server too much, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this SQL Server on premise (as opposed to Azure SQL database) then you could look into using the Streaming API for extended events (also used by SSMS when viewing the live results data). This is what is used by this project https://github.com/spaghettidba/XESmartTarget - I don't work with Python so not sure how straightforward it is from there. Though maybe you could just use that program itself

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the SQL server is on premise.  I will look into Streaming API now. Thank you!

Comment: So you can set up an extended event session with no targets and then  the "Watch Live Data" option creates an entry in `sys.dm_xe_session_targets` with target_name of 'event_stream' - but I think this is only accessible via .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/targets-for-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#xevent-net-namespaces-and-c

Comment: Could also just do a periodic read of `sys.dm_xe_session_targets` with the right joins see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/selects-and-joins-from-system-views-for-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#c7-dmv-select-casting-target_data-column-to-xml

Comment: You can use what profiler uses, a trace. By then calling fn_trace_table function from time to time, you can get the trace data. Although, tracing stuff to provide functionality to users sounds a bit hacky in my eyes...

Comment: @siggemannen How would you do it? I have never tried to do something like this before, but was tasked with trying to figure it out.